# Verification of results given by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using NDSolve. The differential equations used are obtained by applying method of lines to actual governing equation. The system includes differential equations that govern the convection-diffusion process in a micro channel. I am doing mass balance over the channel as a verification of the results that I got. I see a error of 3-4 % in mass which is not acceptable. Further it is increasing with increase in the number of grid points in the domain.

I read an article on how to check the results from NDSOlve.http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CheckTheResultsOfNDSolve.html

And I followed to this to plot the residual with time and got the following graph.[image]

So what does this mean? Are the results obtained accurate or not?

I have 2 sets of ODEs. I could solve 1st set accurately. Problem is with 2nd set.
Following is the first system.
[image: First set of ODEs with BCs and ICs]

I give the values for the variables pea1,pea2,dr,ks,k,lambda. I know w10 and w20 as a function of x,y.

Following is the second system[image: Second set of ODEs with BCs and ICs]
[image]
I get the solution for c10 and c20 from set 1. I use it in set 2. I give values for pet1 and pet2. I know u11,u21,v11,v21,w11,w21 as a function of x,y.

In the problem x=k is the interface. I specified k as 0. Fluid 1 flows left to it and fluid 2 flows right to it. My spatial domain is in x (-1,1) and y(-1,1).

Comment: Well, it is decreasing, yes? Note that you are effectively plotting the logarithm of the resudual; so, the smaller the absolute difference… I'll let you finish the sentence. ;)

Comment: Also: `NDSolve[]` can directly apply the method of lines to PDEs. Have you tried feeding your actual PDEs to `NDSolve[]` instead of going through all that discretization yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Firstly,thanks for your response. No I did not try the default setting for method of lines that Mathematica provides. I had incorporated the boundary conditions into differential equations during discretizaton process and converted the whole system into initial value problem. Will there be any difference if I use the default setting?

Comment: I suspect that the outcome may be hard to predict. However, since you are none too happy with your current result, maybe you could try what @Guess suggested, and report back.

Comment: I have coupled PDEs and each PDE has a different spatial domain with a common interface. I don't know if I can implement Method of lines on such system directly using NDSolve. Can I directly give my PDEs, BCs and ICs to NDSolve? Can anyone please suggest me a method for that?

Comment: Well, did you already look at the docs for `NDSolve[]`? Better yet, why not post your actual PDE along with the associated conditions?

Comment: I updated the question that I posted. Please take a look.

Comment: post actual code. Surely you don't expect folks to retype stuff from your notebook.

Comment: @george, the problem is that OP might just post his manual application of the method of lines here. Sai, in case you don't know: the system can render $\LaTeX$ expressions here through MathJax; consider posting your equations in that form instead of images.

Comment: $$\text{dri}=1;$$  $$\text{$\lambda $i}=1;$$  $$\text{ki}=0;$$  $$\text{ksi}=1;$$  $$\text{$\mu $ri}=1;$$   $$\text{w10}=1;$$   $$\text{w20}=1;$$   $$\text{z0}=50;$$

Comment: $$\text{pea1i}=100;$$ $$\text{pea2i}=100;$$ $$\text{pet1i}=1000;$$ $$\text{pet2i}=1000;$$ $$\text{$\epsilon $i}=0.1;$$

Comment: $$\text{pea1i} \text{w10} \frac{\partial \text{c1}(t,x,y)}{\partial t}=\text{$\lambda $i}^2 \frac{\partial ^2\text{c1}(t,x,y)}{\partial y\, \partial y}+\frac{\partial ^2\text{c1}(t,x,y)}{\partial x\, \partial x},$$ $$\text{pea2i} \text{w20} \frac{\partial \text{c2}(t,x,y)}{\partial t}=\text{$\lambda $i}^2 \frac{\partial ^2\text{c2}(t,x,y)}{\partial y\, \partial y}+\frac{\partial ^2\text{c2}(t,x,y)}{\partial x\, \partial x}$$

Comment: $$\text{c1}^{(0,1,0)}(t,-1,y)=0,\text{c2}^{(0,1,0)}(t,1,y)=0,\text{c1}^{(0,0,1)}(t,x,1)=0,\text{c1}^{(0,0,1)}(t,x,-1)=0,\text{c2}^{(0,0,1)}(t,x,1)=0,\text{c2}^{(0,0,1)}(t,x,-1)=0,\text{dri} \text{c1}^{(0,1,0)}(t,\text{ki},y)=\text{c2}^{(0,1,0)}(t,\text{ki},y),\text{c1}(t,\text{ki},y)=\text{ksi} \text{c2}(t,\text{ki},y),\text{c1}(0,x,y)=1,\text{c2}(0,x,y)=0$$

Comment: I tried implementing method of lines via NDSolve for above system. I encountered an error saying that the boundary conditions that I mentioned at x=ki do not lie on any edge of the domain.

Comment: You should have edited your question instead.